# RequestMapping not working with multi-level URLs

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a scenario where I'm making a simple get request through a link and my @RequestMapping configuration is not behaving as I'd expect.

Within an anchor tag I reference a url with the following pattern '/action-plan/export/pdf?token=xxx&taskId=1111&taskId=2222...'

Within my controller class I have this mapping at the class level:

```
@RequestMapping("/action-plan/export")
```

And this mapping at the method level

```
@RequestMapping(value="/pdf", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String exportToPdf(@RequestParam("taskId") String[] taskIds,
            @RequestParam("token") String[] encryptedEmplId, ModelMap model)
```

But every time I try this I get a 404 page not found error and the following Spring exception:

> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException: No matching handler method found for servlet request: path '/pdf', method 'GET', parameters map['taskId' -> array['1962326', '1962264', '1962317', '1962328', '1962324', '1962427', '1962325', '1962323', '1963147', '1962327', '1962318', '1962329', '1962330'], 'token' -> array['xxxx']]

I've noticed that when I remove the "/pdf?" portion of the link and remove 'value="/pdf"' from the method @RequestMapping it works fine. For the life of me I don't understand why adding /pdf to the url and RequestMapping is not working.

Comment: Please post your web.xml servlet mapping for the DispatcherServlet

Comment: I believe you just need to change it to @RequestMapping("/action-plan/export/*") and the @RequestMapping(value="pdf" ettc) without the slash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think danny.lesnik's answer was pretty close but I'm writing my own answer so I can be more verbose.

I was working on a different project and figured out why the above doesn't work. In reference to my original question here is the relevant web.xml servlet mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/action-plan/export/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I noticed that whatever portion of the path I included in the  of web.xml was not being included in the evaluation of RequestMapping values. I would have thought this bean configuration would have prevented that scenario (note the "alwaysUseFullPath" property):

```
<bean id="annotationHandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="order" value="2"/>
        <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Maybe someone can shed some light on this detail for me.

In any case, thanks danny.lesnik

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your problem and solved it by mapping servlet using .action extentions.

For example:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/test")
public class DefaultController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/pdf.action", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView indexView(@RequestParam("taskId") String[] taskIds,
            @RequestParam("token") String[] encryptedEmplId){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
    return mv;
    }
```

Spring XML mapping:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.vanilla.controllers" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix">
<value>/</value>
</property>
<property name="suffix">
<value>.jsp</value>
</property>
</bean>
```

and this web.xml servlet mapping

```
 <display-name>SpringMvcServlet</display-name>
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringMvcServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringMvcServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

This code resolves this url

/test/pdf.action?token=3&token=4&taskId=4

flawless.

Comment: Does your solution work if you add another layer to the class level url, such as @RequestMapping(value="/test/level2")?

Comment: I was working on another project and somewhat confirmed your answer. In reference to my original question here is the relevant web.xml servlet mapping:  `<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/action-plan/export/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>` .